# do-try-catch usage in Swift 2

Tags: xcode, swift, try-catch

Is this usage not correct? why? The file name I use is correct!

[image]

on the right side of the playground I would aspect to see the content of the txt file.

Comment: is the location of the file also good? Is your play code file able to access it?

Comment: Is there a reason for posting a picture rather than copy/paste the code?

Comment: Use `catch let error as NSError { print(error.localizedDescription) }` to get a possible error description.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your post and show the actual code as text instead of screenshots. Others can't copy and paste from your images. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1402846) for details. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In terms of why this failed, you'd have to look at the `error` object and examine why it failed. You're catching the `error`, so look at it:

```
func read(path: String) throws {
    do {
        try NSString(contentsOfFile: path, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    } catch {
        print("cannot read: \(error)")
    }
}
```

That will tell you why it failed.

---

Having said all of that, this doesn't quite make sense: First, you're reading the contents of the path into the `NSString`, but discarding it. You presumably want to return this string or do something with it.

Second, `read` has been declared in such a way as to say that it `throws` error, but it doesn't really. It catches any error that might happen itself, but doesn't throw anything. You have to decide whether `read` will throw any errors it generates, or whether it will handle them without throwing any error, or both.

Assuming the caller was going to handle the error, you might just forego any `do`-`try`-`catch` construct in `read` altogether:

```
func read(path: String) throws -> NSString? {
    return try NSString(contentsOfFile: path, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
}
```

Then you can let the caller catch any error that `NSString` threw. For example, you might catch the "not found" error:

```
do {
    let string = try read(path)
    // do something with string
} catch let error as NSError where error.domain == NSCocoaErrorDomain && error.code == NSCocoaError.FileReadNoSuchFileError.rawValue {
    // not found handling here
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

If you really wanted `read` to not only catch the error, but also make sure it `throws` one as well, then you'd need to have to explicitly `throw` an error from its `catch` block. You can use this pattern using either your own `ErrorType` or just throwing the original error you just caught:

```
func read(path: String) throws -> NSString? {
    var string: NSString?
    do {
        string = try NSString(contentsOfFile: path, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    } catch {
        // do whatever special handling you want here

        // but also throw error so caller is informed that there was an issue
        throw error
    }
    return string
}
```

Frankly, I think the pattern outlined above is simpler, but given your code snippet, I thought I'd also illustrate this latter pattern, too, in case you needed something like that.

Answer (score 0):

I am also learning, so I wrote a little demo. Hope it helps.   [image]

Comment: Please **[edit]** your post and show the actual code as text instead of screenshots. Others can't copy and paste from your images. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1402846) for details. Thank you.